# Make a JNLP Web-Start applet resizable

Tags: java, applet, jnlp, java-web-start

We have an applet used to run our app in-browser, but we also provide a JNLP web-start option. When the web-start window launches, it is not resizable or maximizable and we want to make this possible.

I initially thought it be a simple setting in the JNLP file but now I'm not sure. How should I be approaching this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no setting in the JNLP that caters for a resizable applet viewer (which is what JWS uses to show floating applets).

OTOH a little bit of hackery might get you there.  I can recall doing this some (long) time ago.  I think from memory it basically involved [`getParent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getParent%28%29) in a loop until `null`, the last component before that was a `JFrame`.  Once you have a reference to the frame, you can call `setResizable(true)`.

In fact, (considers) you might also look into [`JComponent.getTopLevelAncestor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getTopLevelAncestor%28%29) for getting a reference to the root frame.  AFIU that method did not exist when I tried the experiment.  (Yes, it was ***that*** long ago.)

Of course, an overall better strategy is to create a hybrid application/applet.  Embed  the applet into a browser, and launch the frame by JWS.  This provides full control over the GUI.

Comment: This might seem a weird question, but can you grab the Applet instance  from generic Java code? Our applet class is actually a 3rd-party library which handles loading our app as a kind of plugin. That applet reads the name of our main class as a <param> and instances it, without passing us the Applet instance.

Comment: The 3rd-party applet is passed the name of our 'app' class as a param, and instances via reflection. So we are never passed _any_ Java GUI object, since in-game we use a special game UI framework.

Comment: The GUI classes are totally abstracted away from AWT/SWT... they derive directly from `Object`. `getWindows()` would be the preferred route, but we are supporting Java 5 and that is documented as being a 6 feature.

Comment: *"we are supporting Java 5"*  In that case, look to [`Frame.getFrames()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#getFrames%28%29).  It is 1.2+

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit of code I added at the end of my `init` method that made my applet resizable. My class extends `JApplet`.

```
Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this);
if (window instanceof JFrame) {
    JFrame frame = (JFrame) window;
    if (!frame.isResizable()) {
        frame.setResizable(true);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I still have this problem even though is 2022.

No, I am not part of the dev team and I do not have access to source code.

What I did was use shell script to change the window size in the JNLP file to my liking every time I downloaded the JNLP.

It's not resizable but of course I can change window size in shell script and restart JNLP application.

```
TMPFILE=/tmp/app-resized.jnlp

cat ~/Downloads/app.jnlp | sed -e 's/width="1470" height="1250"/width="1024" height="768"/' > $TMPFILE
rm ~/Downloads/app.jnlp


javaws $TMPFILE
```